# What should go in my project.clj to run Om with Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript, om

I looked at the [Github Om page](https://github.com/swannodette/om) but it is not clear which version I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see https://github.com/swannodette/om#using-it

Your project.clj should include something like the following:

```
(defproject foo "0.1.0"
  ...
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2173"]
                 [om "0.5.3"]]
  ...)
```